# PHP - Youtube API validation errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

I have created a Youtube small web application using the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php). The application sends messages to my customers, and if a message is not sent successfully i print the Youtube error to know where is the problem, through this code :

```
try {  // Send the message.
    $sentMessage = $yt->sendVideoMessage( $body, null, $videoId, $customerName );
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e) {                 
    $errorReport .= "- YouTube Error: " . $e->getRawResponseBody() . "\n";
}
```

Some messages are being sent fine, but sometimes strange Youtube errors are being print, and i can't figure out where the problem is. For example it prints :

> - YouTube Error: 11
>     Validation failed

And this sometimes :

> - YouTube Error: 9
>     Forbidden

**Is there a guide that refers to these error numbers, so i can fix my code according to their meaning ?**

Comment: What's the output of $e->getMessage() (as opposed to getRawResponseBody()) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigation i found what those 2 errors mean :

> YouTube Error: 11 Validation failed

This error occurred because there was a missing character in the video id. It was typed wrong, so this error seems to occur if there was some wrong entry in the sendVideoMessage(...) parameters.

> YouTube Error: 9 Forbidden

This error occurs because i have sent too many messages at the same time, so Youtube thought i am sending spam messages.

That took some time, but now things are fixed :)

If someone knows a guide explaining all possible Youtube API errors, please share it so everyone can benefit from that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses

Comment: I've already checked that, but i don't even see my error numbers there !